# Replace Content with Javascript/Jquery

Tags: javascript, css

http://jsfiddle.net/bUjx7/31

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>

<style type="text/css">
.fieldsgame1 {
    display:none;
}
.fieldsgame2 {
    display:none;
}
.fieldsgame3 {
    display:none;
}
</style>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.tablereplace a').click(function () {
        $('.fieldsmatch').fadeOut(0);
        $('.fieldsgame1').fadeOut(0);
        $('.fieldsgame2').fadeOut(0);
        $('.fieldsgame3').fadeOut(0);
        var region = $(this).attr('data-region');
        $('#' + region).fadeIn(0);
    });
});
</script>
```

Put this into my WordPress header. CSS is fine. HTML is fine. Javascript isn't working. Help?

Comment: Try replacing the first line of the script with `jQuery(document).ready(function($) {`

Comment: What isn't working? The fiddle is working.

Comment: @howderek http://kperovic.com/ygoverdose/constructed-4/#vsfield The live demo. The only row with the HTML is the "Agents" row and it doesn't change.

Comment: @FabrícioMatté That didn't change anything. =\

Comment: Weird then. WP automatically puts jQuery in no-conflict mode, so that should've helped in that case. Can't see anything else wrong with your code.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really sure what "isn't working" (since the Fiddle you're showing is working fine), but I did manage to clean up your code a bit. It's more [DRY](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself), `fadeOut` with speed of 0 is the same as `hide()`/`show()`, & [jQuery.data()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.data/) is used to retrieve the `data-region`.

**HTML**

```
<div class="tablereplace">
<a data-region="fieldsmatch" href="#">Match</a>
<a data-region="fieldsgame1" href="#">Game 1</a>
<a data-region="fieldsgame2" href="#">Game 2</a>
<a data-region="fieldsgame3" href="#">Game 3</a>
<div id="fieldsmatch" class="fieldsmatch">8-0</div>
<div id="fieldsgame1" class="fieldsgame">7-1</div>
<div id="fieldsgame2" class="fieldsgame">6-2</div>
<div id="fieldsgame3" class="fieldsgame">1-0</div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.fieldsgame {
    display:none;
}
```

**JS**

```
$('.tablereplace a').click(function () {

    $('#fieldsmatch, .fieldsgame').hide();
    var region = $(this).data('region');
    $('#' + region).show();

});
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bUjx7/33/).

**=== UPDATE ===**

Based on your comment, I found the following *difference* on the live page:

```
<a href="#vsfield" data-region="fieldsmatch">Match</a>
<a href="#vsfield" data-region="fieldsgame1">Game 1</a>
<a href="#vsfield" data-region="fieldsgame2">Game 2</a>
<a href="#vsfield" data-region="fieldsgame3">Game 3</a>

<div class="tablereplace">
    <div class="fieldsmatch" id="fieldsmatch">8-0</div>
    <div class="fieldsgame" id="fieldsgame1">7-1</div>
    <div class="fieldsgame" id="fieldsgame2">6-2</div>
    <div class="fieldsgame" id="fieldsgame3">1-0</div>
</div>
```

Your specified `click` function is based on the `.tablereplace a` selector. But, on your site, there isn't any `a` found inside the `.tablereplace` . In other words, your HTML is wrong.

Comment: http://kperovic.com/ygoverdose/constructed-4 is the live example. "Win Rates vs. Field" and the first row "Agents" has the demo. Any ideas?

Comment: Sorry meant to tag you @MarcoK

Comment: I'm not sure I follow. Should I just move the div class="tablereplace" above the actual links? Because I just tried that to no avail.

Comment: Not sure if I'm tagging properly in my replies. Sorry @MarcoK

Comment: No. This selector: `$('.tablereplace a')` means "for every `a` inside an element with class `.tablereplace`". Since there isn't any, the `click` event is never fired. You can do two things: 1) Move the `a`'s inside the `.tablereplace` element, or 2) Change your JS selector to `$("a[data-region]")` . Good luck!

Comment: Believe it or not, the problem seems to be that loading Javascript in the header didn't carry over to the post. I'm not really sure why that is though. But I loaded Javascript in the actual post and the script works as originally intended.